# Проблемы с vue cli на Linux(Ubunta)

Tags: linux, vue.js, vue-cli

Получилось установить:
`sudo npm install -g @vue/cli`
Получилось создать проект:
`sudo vue create vue-project`
Но столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Каждый раз когда ввожу изменения в существующий файл .vue запрашивает пароль для сохранения и дальнейшего отображения (ранее при работе с html, css, javascript ничего такого не требовалось). Так-же не могу создать новый файл .vue пишет ошибку

Comment: Ну так зачем вы sudo использовали-то, удалите всё что вы насоздавали с sudo и переустановите заново без sudo

Comment: Можно ещё было из папки с проектом выполнить `sudo chown -R юзер:группа .`, чтобы файлы перешли от рута во владение пользователя.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему. Переустановил пакеты yarn на линуксе и создал проект через yarn global add @vue/cli

Comment: Вообще, обычно пакеты, отвечающие за сборку или работу конкретного проекта ставятся в проект а не в global. В global ставится только yarn. И то, некоторые его в dev кладут, а не в global.